# Page Does Not Redirect to Index With Correct Username and Password

Tags: php, mysql, session, redirect

I have a number of users that can use a secure part of a website, Right now I am concentrating on making this able to login and log out. I can't get this page to redirect to the original page. When I first go to the index.php it DOES redirect to the Login.php like it should. But when I enter a correct username and password into the page and submit it, it simply redirects back to the login.php. But it doesn't set the parameters of $_SESSION["correct"] to false like it should IF it was to redirect back to login.php, instead it DOES set it to TRUE. $_SESSION["correct"] shouldn't even be set until a correct username or password is entered. This is all worked within my verify.php. I am echoing the values of the 'logged' and 'correct' session data to verify if they are set and what their values are.

LOGIN.PHP

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>Administration Login</h3>
    </div>
    <form action="verify.php" method="post">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <?php
                    echo $_SESSION['logged'] . '<br>';
                    echo $_SESSION['correct'] . '<br>';
                ?>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" required autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

VERIFY.PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require ("../_php/connectInfo.php");

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $query = "SELECT id, username, password FROM info";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($row['password'] == $password && $row['username'] == $username) {

                $_SESSION["logged"] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION["correct"] = TRUE;
                header("location: index.php");
                exit;
            }
        }
        $_SESSION["correct"] = FALSE;
        header("location: login.php");  
    } else {
        header("location: login.php");  
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the top of every page requiring the use of session variables?

Comment: I believe so, The login.php does have it, I just didn't list it because there is confidential information that comes after where I have put the session_start() command

Comment: Jay I will concentrate on security once I can get basic functionality down.

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I completely get what you are saying, but the security is actually being done at a different level. First I have the obvious SSL cert, second I think I want to add security later ONCE I know how to get this working properly. This isn't a school project, and I am more concerned with getting it WORKING than with security. Security not only takes proper practice BUT it also requires a lot more testing than what I can give it at the moment. Its a matter of me being the only developer for this site and having to prioritize this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101946/discussion-between-tyler-lazenby-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: First of all: you don't check username and password, you check only password. Then: in my PHP configuration, `$_SESSION["correct"]` and `$_SESSION["CORRECT"]` are not the same thing. Have you tried to put a `die('OK');` after second `if` loop to see if the password is found?

Comment: Yes and indeed it is found Fusion

Comment: You really need to learn about `where` clauses in SQL. You're doing the equivalent of driving to a grocery store, buying the ENTIRE inventory, driving it all home, then throwing it all in the garbage except for the one candy bar you really wanted.

Comment: I tried to do that with `SELECT id, username, password FROM info WHERE username = '$username';` but it would give an error and not even run the code IF the username wasn't found

Comment: I should probably mention that once I have put in a correct username and password and if I manually go to the index.php it acts as if I logged in and stay at the secure page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `die();` or `exit;` instead of `break;`:

```
(...)
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['password'] == $password) {

        $_SESSION["logged"] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION["correct"] = TRUE;
        header("location: index.php");
        break;                            #  -----
    }                                     #      |
}                                         #      |
$_SESSION["CORRECT"] = FALSE;             #  <----
header("location: login.php");  
(...)
```

When you break the `while` loop, you define `$_SESSION['CORRECT']` as `False` and send the user to login page, in any case.

Comment: I do that and now it just stays at verify.php

Comment: I have replicate your code and it's work for me (with `die`). I don't understand what's your problem.  It's really strange question. You have any way to check error log? Maybe can help.

Comment: I enabled all my error reporting and got the following error: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/prouda/public_html/cms/verify.php:1) in /home/prouda/public_html/cms/verify.php on line 17`

Comment: You have omitted some line in code posted here? because it's the line 15 of code above. there are something before `<?php` tag?

Comment: Nope, no code exists before that, HOWEVER might this be because this file is the action for a post on the `login.php`?

Comment: I don't think. After all, the `login.php` redirect worked, right?

Comment: Yes and I figured it out, you have to put session_destroy() and the session_start() to get this to redirect.